# Xamarin Grid how to know which button is pressed

Tags: c#, xamarin, grid, xamarin.forms, row

I am working with a grid of xamarin forms, I have a event handler when a button of the grid is clicked button I don't know how to know in which row and column the button is.

This is my grid code:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" ColumnSpacing="6" RowSpacing="5" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Constant=-20}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                         Property=Height,
                         Factor=0.50 }">

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Text="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Text="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button3" Text="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button4" Text="4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button5" Text="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button6" Text="6" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>

    <Button x:Name="button7" Text="7" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button8" Text="8" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button9" Text="9" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button10" Text="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button11" Text="11" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button12" Text="12" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>

    <Button x:Name="button13" Text="13" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button14" Text="14" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button15" Text="15" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button16" Text="16" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button17" Text="17" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button18" Text="18" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>

    <Button x:Name="button19" Text="19" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button20" Text="20" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button21" Text="21" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button22" Text="22" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button23" Text="23" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button24" Text="24" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>

    <Button x:Name="button25" Text="25" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button26" Text="26" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button27" Text="27" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button28" Text="28" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button29" Text="29" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
    <Button x:Name="button30" Text="30" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5" Clicked="handle_clicked"/>
</Grid>
```

And eventHandler code:

```
void handle_clicked(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Button thebutton = (Button) sender;
        int row = ?;
        int column = ?;

        //Display picker view with options
        //Displaypickerview();

    }
```

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

Your answer works but why is Grid capitalised.

Because in my grid code I have grid Name lowercase so I thought you would use lowercase so you search thebutton in my grid.

Comment: Grid.GetRow/Grid.GetColumn are static methods of the Grid class: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Grid.GetRow/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/. The name of the methods are not related to the name of your actual Grid in any way.

Comment: I find it a little bit weird but oh wel i works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button theButton = (Button) sender;
int row = Grid.GetRow(theButton);
int column = Grid.GetColumn(theButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

About your question why it is with a capital Grid.

Static Methods are methods that are not instance based. They come directly from the class itself. Which in this case is the class called "Grid".

If you don't understand the concept of classes vs instance vs objects read this:

https://alfredjava.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/class-vs-object-vs-instance/

It's the shortest explanation I could find:

Comment: Well i never had any programming lessons so thank you for the link. Funny you made an account just to post this.

Comment: It's funny that you noticed that! Anyway, do you understand now why it is 'Grid' and not 'grid'? Hope my answer helped you